# How to duplicate a cURL command with file as body

Tags: go, curl, generator, hootsuite

is there anyone can help me to converting this cURL command to Go?

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: image/jpg' \
     -H "Content-Length: 132093" \
     -T "/Users/ikmal/Downloads/catcute.jpg" \
     "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/18395606_a9245dd7-73d6-4392-af4a-1cd9bf359cfb.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIM7ASX2JTE3ZFAAA&Expires=1543304067&Signature=n9sZkQ%2BF1DGuiYHqixrrvmoxIXQ%3D"
```

I already try generator like:

**1. https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go/**

it created Go code like this:

```
// Generated by curl-to-Go: https://mholt.github.io/curl-to-go

req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/18395606_a9245dd7-73d6-4392-af4a-1cd9bf359cfb.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIM7ASX2JTE3ZFAAA&Expires=1543304067&Signature=n9sZkQ%2BF1DGuiYHqixrrvmoxIXQ%3D", nil)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "image/jpg")
req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "132093")

resp, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
```

**2. https://curl.trillworks.com/**

it created Go code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/18395606_a9245dd7-73d6-4392-af4a-1cd9bf359cfb.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIM7ASX2JTE3ZFAAA&Expires=1543304067&Signature=n9sZkQ%2BF1DGuiYHqixrrvmoxIXQ%3D", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "image/jpg")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "132093")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", bodyText)
}
```

But neither gives me proper code because when I run those on project, it returning some error, because it doesn't generate this part:

```
-T "/Users/ikmal/Downloads/catcute.jpg"
```

and generate it as "nil" instead.

**UPDATE :**

What I have done for this problem is adding this code:

```
file, err := os.Open("/Users/ikmal/Downloads/catcute.jpg")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer file.Close()
```

so I put the variable "file" into body request, here is my final code:

```
func main(){
    file, err := os.Open("/Users/ikmal/Downloads/catcute.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/18395606_a9245dd7-73d6-4392-af4a-1cd9bf359cfb.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIM7ASX2JTE3ZFAAA&Expires=1543304067&Signature=n9sZkQ%2BF1DGuiYHqixrrvmoxIXQ%3D", file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "image/jpg")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Length", "132093")
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyText, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", bodyText)
}
```

then when I build and run this program, it returning response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>NotImplemented</Code>
   <Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message>
   <Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>
   <RequestId>FBD2CEAF71EA4DEA</RequestId>
   <HostId>K6hDrHIJr5YtoIBn2d64bfuLBgs6F17gKQV9jrTJ31X987A5gshhqtnKDs3lW2uSliBJwk1pri4=</HostId>
</Error>
```

It seems the error came from headers problem, but I'm sure I type the header correctly. Is there something wrong that I missed?

Comment: You seem to know what the problem is (the request body is nil). What have you done to try to fix it?

Comment: see https://golang.org/src/net/http/transfer.go for a working example of a go file transfer program

Comment: @Flimzy thanks for remind me, i've updated my question, please take a look

Comment: @Vorsprung thank you for suggestion, i will take a look for that link.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Comment: My suggestion: Remove the 'Content-Length' header. It may be that the content is sent using chunked transfer encoding, which would conflict with a content-length header.

Comment: @Flimzy i tried, but it return same response as i declared in the question

Answer (score 0):

You must using `multipart` to upload content of image.

```
f, err := os.Open("./Users/ikmal/Downloads/catcute.jpg")
if err != nil{
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer f.Close()

var buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
writer := multipart.NewWriter(buf)

part, _ := writer.CreateFormFile("image", "dont care about name")
io.Copy(part, f)

writer.Close()

req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "https://hootsuite-video.s3.amazonaws.com/production/18395606_a9245dd7-73d6-4392-af4a-1cd9bf359cfb.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIM7ASX2JTE3ZFAAA&Expires=1543304067&Signature=n9sZkQ%2BF1DGuiYHqixrrvmoxIXQ%3D", buf)
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())

client := &http.Client{}
res, _ := client.Do(req)
defer res.Body.Close()
b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
fmt.Println(string(b))
```